# Magento2.4 decrease stock quantity when invoice is generated

Tags: magento2, invoice, quantity

Magento2.4 I need to decrease qty only when payment is successful which is when invoice is generated.

In short, need to reduce qty when Invoice is generated

For that I uesd this module https://github.com/Vendic/magento2-stock-change-after-payment

But the issue is quantity is also getting reduced when shipment is done. i.e. Quantity decrease twice

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is old, but what you might need to do is to disable the default Magento MSI stock decrease when the order is shipped. You could do this by disabling the event that triggers that stock reduction:

```
<event name="sales_order_shipment_save_after">
    <observer name="inventory_sales_source_deduction_processor" disabled="true"/>
</event>
```